# installing apache httpd server on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, apache2, tomcat, lighttpd

I have 5 systems running apache tomcat server, for **load balancing** i need to install **apache httpd server**, how should i do this, please provide me some useful links and your opinions on this,
 thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can just

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2
```

If Tomcat is working on 80 port, than you might need more configurations, like default port etc...
Hope it helps.

Comment: i have installed apache2, any idea about configurations? /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file is empty for me

Comment: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is now configuration file. you can add configuration to httpd.conf, I think it's still included when starting, if you have old httpd.conf and you just want to copy it. But you will find everything you need in apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

To install apache2 you can do it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Now if you don't want see this warning every-time you restart apache service

```
 ... waiting .apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Now you want to give a server's fully qualified domain name

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and name it using the keyword serverName

```
serverName localhost
```

I named localhost you can just choose whatever you like.

***You don't have any problems with port numbers since tomcat run on port 8080 by default and apache run on port 80 by default.***

But anyway if you want to just change the port number of your apache.

**To change the port apache is running on you can do it like this:**

Open /etc/apache2/ports.conf file, enter:

```
gksudo /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

To make the server accept connections on port 8010 for example instead of 80 search for the word `Listen 80` and replace with:

```
Listen 8010
```